# x11 - sending a mouse click without moving a pointer

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

Let's assume that I know window id. Then I can send a mouse click to that window this way (it is a fullscreen window so root and window coordinates are the same):

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if(display == NULL)
{
    std::cout<<"Cannot open display"<<std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
XWarpPointer(display, None, RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 200);
XEvent event;

memset(&event, 0x00, sizeof(event));

event.type = ButtonPress;
event.xbutton.button = button;
event.xbutton.same_screen = True;
event.xbutton.root = RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display));
event.xbutton.window = 75497473;
event.xbutton.subwindow = 0;
event.xbutton.x_root = 300;
event.xbutton.y_root = 200;
event.xbutton.x = 300;
event.xbutton.y = 200;
event.xbutton.state = 0;

XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, ButtonPressMask, &event) == 0)
XFlush(display);
usleep(100000);

event.type = ButtonRelease;
event.xbutton.state = 0x100;

XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, ButtonReleaseMask, &event) == 0)
XFlush(display);
```

That code doesn't work if I remove:

```
XWarpPointer(display, None, RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 200);
```

I don't use XQueryPointer so I don't understand where is a problem. Is it possible to send a mouse click without using XWarpPointer ?

Comment: If you change the x/y position to XWarpPointer, where does the mouse press event occur? At (300,200) or the position given to XWarpPointer? Also, you set event.xbutton.state to 0 for the ButtonPressEvent, indicating no button was actually pressed. Finally, you are using a hardcoded value '0x100' for ButtonRelease; don't do that, use the Button*Mask constants (see http://www.tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [XTestFakeMotionEvent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xtestfakemotionevent) from [XTEST](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xextproto/xtest.txt) extension

Comment: [for a discussion of the differences between these two approaches, see e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42013047/1509695)